# Linq Group By not taking inner entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I am using entity framework and doing a group by over a table. My query is a follows:-

```
var brokerPaymentLists = dbContext.BrokerPayments
    .Include("PaymentDetail")
    .Where(bp => bp.IdPaymentStatus == (long)EntityModel.Additions.Variables.PaymentStatus.ALLOTED)
    .GroupBy(bp => bp.IdBroker,
    (key, g) => new
    {
        IdBroker = key.Value,
        BrokerPayments = g.ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

I have included PaymentDetail but after grouping by i can see that the paymentdetail for each item in the BrokerPayments i null. Any suggestion why this is the case, also how can i do the group by such that I can my my paymentDetail insisde each of the BrokerPayments;

Comment: I found a blog post that might help, though it was written in 2008, so it may be outdated: http://wildermuth.com/2008/12/28/Caution_when_Eager_Loading_in_the_Entity_Framework

Answer (score 1):

The eagerly loading by using `Include` requires the shape of the data to do not be changed since the `Include` is applied. In your case this means the query must return `IQueryable<BrokerPayments>`. But the `GroupBy` operator changes the shape because it returns `IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`. Same will happen with projections and custom joins.

As a workaround you can execute grouping in LINQ to Objects like:

```
var brokerPaymentLists = dbContext.BrokerPayments
    .Include("PaymentDetail")
    .Where(bp => bp.IdPaymentStatus == (long)EntityModel.Additions.Variables.PaymentStatus.ALLOTED)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(bp => bp.IdBroker,
    (key, g) => new
    {
        IdBroker = key.Value,
        BrokerPayments = g
    });
```

NOTE: pay attention that the query exectuion will not be defferd

Comment: Don't use `ToList()`, at least when trying to convert to a Linq to objects query, use `AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: @Jeff you are completely right. I corrected my answer.